# jquery video background plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm testing a jQuery video background plugin and i don't have the same behavior in firefox than the demo site.

the plugin demo site:
http://www.georgepaterson.com/sandbox/jquery-html5-video-background-demo/

the video plays in Firefox

my demo site:
http://willychataigner.com/2020/georgepaterson-jquery-videobackground-8b3535a/

the video doesn't play in Firefox

something i have noticed is that when i try the 3 different video format url in a new window

these 3 video format play for the plugin demo site:

http://www.georgepaterson.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-videobackground/video/big-buck-bunny.mp4

http://www.georgepaterson.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-videobackground/video/big-buck-bunny.webm

http://www.georgepaterson.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-videobackground/video/big-buck-bunny.ogv

but on my demo site these 2 video format don't play. i get a window to save the video on my computer

http://www.willychataigner.com/2020/georgepaterson-jquery-videobackground-8b3535a/video/big-buck-bunny.webm

http://www.willychataigner.com/2020/georgepaterson-jquery-videobackground-8b3535a/video/big-buck-bunny.ogv

I thought that this might be a hosting issue but i tested on 3 different hosting server and same issue!

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks and good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely your Content-type (MIME Type).

Some examples are:

```
mp2 audio/mpeg
mp3 audio/mpeg
mp4 video/mp4
mpe video/mpeg
mpeg    video/mpeg
mpg video/mpeg
mpga    audio/mpeg
```

In Apache this is in the file **mime.types**. Just edit it in a text editor and save. For more information on Apache see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

In IIS follow these instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

You will need to add the type specific to the video you are wanting to play.

Comment: thanks for the reply i will ask my hosting provider if he can add those two format

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you're right and it's a problem with your server.
Try to create a .htaccess file with the following content:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Not sure if the file has to be in the root directory or in the folder with the html-documents, just give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

I got some more good [jQuery video background plugins](http://gojquery.com/jquery-video-background-plugins/), which you can use for creating fullscreen video backgrounds.

Comment: Please do not write an answer that is only a link to an external source. If that link changes this answer becomes invalid. Linking to external sources is encouraged, but you should also replicate relevant data in your answer.